# Why my Matrix multiplicator isn't working?

Tags: matrix, lua, lua-table

I tried to make an matrix multiplicator in lua but when the C[x][y] goes out of the for loop the C[x][y] table gets an wrong value. Can anybody help me?

Code:

```
function Matrix_Multiplicator_Square(A,B)
    if not(#A == #B) then
        error("Hey! The matrix is not square.")
    end

    local C = {}
    local Model = {}
    for l=1,#A,1 do
        table.insert(Model, 0)
    end
    for l=1,#A,1 do
        table.insert(C, Model)
    end

    for y=1,#A,1 do
        for x=1,#A,1 do
            for i=1,#A,1 do
                C[x][y] = C[x][y] + A[x][i]*B[i][y] 
            end
            print(C[x][y])
        end 
    end
    print("     --     ",#A)
    for y=1,#A,1 do
        for x=1,#A,1 do
            print(C[x][y])
        end
    end

    return C
end
```

Terminal :
Start
7
22
10
32
--         2
22
22
32
32
22
22
32
32
end

C:\Users\paull\Desktop>

Comment: You should create new `Model` every time instead of using the same `Model` in `table.insert(C, Model)` for the whole matrix.  Otherwise all your rows will be identical as they refer to the same Lua table.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are not initializing the values of the C table correctly. When you insert the Model table into C, it is inserting a reference to the same table, so when you change the values of Model, it is also changing the values of C.

To fix this, you need to create a new table for each element of C. You can do this by changing the line

```lua
table.insert(C, Model)
```

to

```lua
table.insert(C, {unpack(Model)})
```

This will create a new table for each element of C, so when you change the values of Model, it won't affect the values of C.

After making this change, your code should work as expected.